# Beginner at PHP - having issues with cURL

Tags: php, curl, arduino

I am having some issues getting cURL to work in PHP. I'm a complete beginner (as of a few days ago) with PHP.

Basically, I'm trying to grab the output from my Arduino (which is outputting the temperature every 10 seconds) and bring it across to my web-page. The plan is to then store the data in a database of some kind so I can analyse the history/plot graphs etc over time.

Right now I just need to bring the data across though.

The Arduino is spitting out the temp, nothing else, and my router is making that available on the web here - http://2.216.137.236/

My code is as follows:

```
<?php

$Url = "http://2.216.137.236/";
echo "Hello, is this on?" . "<br>";
// is cURL installed?
if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
    echo "cURL not installed!";
    die('Sorry cURL is not installed!');
}
echo "cURL is installed!" . "<br>";

// OK cool - then let's create a new cURL resource handle
$ch = curl_init();

// Now set some options (most are optional)

// Set URL to download
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);

// Include header in result? (0 = yes, 1 = no)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

// Should cURL return or print out the data? (true = return, false = print)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Timeout in seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

// Download the given URL, and return output
$output = curl_exec($ch);

// Close the cURL resource, and free system resources
curl_close($ch);

print_r ($output);
```

?>

But right now all I am getting at my page is 
"Hello, is this on?
cURL is installed!"
with no sign of the temperature anywhere (see here - http://wetdreams.org.uk/ChrisProject/curl_test.php) 
(excuse the URL, kayaking website of mine)

I really hope there isn't some n00by PHP thing that is killing me.

Anyway, hope you can help me out.

**Edit:** My poor little router has crashed trying to serve all your requests, in hindsight probably shouldn't have put the IP up. Will reset it and try again, links might not work afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually this [article](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/programming/php-get-the-contents-of-a-web-page-rss-feed-or-xml-file-into-a-string-variable/) may help you.

The simples way would be to use `file_get_contents("url")` but you can of course use curl if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use php's file_get_contents function if you only need to get what's on the page : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.file-get-contents.php

It's easier for your needs i guess.

Example :

```
<?php

$temperature = file_get_contents("http://2.216.137.236/");
// Process your data here

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, and added this in:

```
echo curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else
{
    echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
}
```

The HTTP code returns 0, and the error is: Curl error: Empty reply from server.

I can't say what's causing this, but it should help to debug further. (I *can* see the webpage's output for the temp in my browser - so I really can't understand why the page is not being served to Curl)

Comment: Hey - thanks, I think my router has gone down since its just a home router. Will try this once its reset and get back to you.

Comment: Ok, just so you know it was returning that *before* your router crashed (It was still giving me a temp when viewing in my browser).